# share directory in win 2008 when password sharing protection is enabled

Tags: networking

Can i share directory without username and password when password sharing protection is enabled. Now i always need username and password for connect to shared folder but i want that everyon can read and write to this folder without username and passwd. OS is win 2008.

I try everything you [jftuga and laurent-rpnet] said but no solution works. Still need username and passwd. Maybe any other idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this by setting share permission to: Everyone / Full Access and then adding NTFS permissions to: Everyone / Full Control.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to share it with permissions for `Anonymous` or `Network users` in order to let non authenticated users access it. `Everyone` is all authenticated users so the user need a login/password to be part of Everyone but I don't have a win server to test.

Answer (score 0):

jftuga's and laurent-rpnet's answers should have worked.  What client OS's are trying to connect to the share?  You may need to change settings to allow &nix or mac clients to connect.

There may also be a problem with the network path being used - does it connect OK with a admin account with rights to the server?

Comment: win 2008 to win 2008. Yes with username and passwd works fine.

Comment: and i am connecting via VPN

Comment: Do you know if users on the LAN experience the same issue, or are you only able to test over VPN?